# php wordpress-how to give url link form download files from a folder?

Tags: php, download

I am unable to download a file from custom database table.

I have created directory with the name same as application id while uploading file,inside that files are inserted.

If i give url path to download its not getting downloaded.

For ex ESTCCB-10094 is my app id.

test.txt is my file which is placed inside ESTCCB-10094.

All files and folder are placed inside ftp .

```
'download' => '<a href="http://www.dev.org/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/ESTCCB-10094/test.txt" >download</a>', $item['FileupName'], __('Download', 'custom_table_example'),
```

Please let me know where i am wrong!!!